# Is it possible to do preprocessing evaluation with something different than a numeric constant using GreenHills?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, greenhills

I am trying to do the following evaluation:
In my header file (define value can change):

```
#define X ((void *) 0)
```

In my function:

```
uint8_t foo() {

   uint8_t value = 0;

#if ( X != 0 )
   value = 1;
#endif

   return value;
}
```

When I compile the code it throws the following errors:

```
#57: this operator is not allowed in a constant expression
#58: this operator is not allowed in a preprocessing expression
```

When I do operations to see if the DEFINE exists (or not) it works fine (#ifdef or #if defined(X)). But what I want is to be able to evaluate the value of X at compile time.
Am I missing any flag or something I need to set in order to be able to make this work? I am using Green Hills compiler.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Standard C which will work with any C compiler.

Comment: Would `X==0` work? If so, then just add `#else` clause...

Comment: Please make plain what `do something` means. Preprocessor statements do not have any direct action.

Comment: The edit is bizzarre. What is the [XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Does a simple `#if X` work?

Comment: Is this the *exact* code you are trying? Or you have "simplified" it?

Comment: Finally you show the real code, and that code is not valid, because `X` is not a numeric constant. The previous version of the question, where you had `#define X 0` is valid, and should work.

Comment: Was it that hard to show the actual code? You just wasted time of several people for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use casts in `#if` expressions<sup>1</sup>. The preprocessor knows nothing about types. (And the only values supported by `#if` are simple integers, so pointers are right out.)

Just use a regular `if` statement:

```
if (X != 0) {
    value = 1;
}
```

The compiler will recognize that the condition is always true (or false, depending) at compile time.

---

<sup>1</sup> Reference: ISO 9899:1999, **6.10.1 Conditional inclusion**:

> 1. The expression that controls conditional inclusion shall be an integer constant expression except that: it shall not contain a cast; [...]

Comment: In fact you *can* use casts in `#if` expressions, but not the particular one the OP tries to use.

Comment: You can use any cast in a preprocessor expression as long as you understand it's compiled in context after the preprocessor step during compilation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger My C99 says otherwise (in 6.10.1/1).

Comment: @nicomp What do you mean by "preprocessor expression"?

Comment: @melpomene, the current C standard is C2011.  I quote its relevant provision (which happens to be numbered the same) in my own answer; it does not contain the prohibition against casts.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yeah, but C11 still converts unknown identifiers to `0`, so how can you even form a cast expression?

Comment: You make an excellent point, and in practice, `gcc` agrees with you.  It's not the final arbiter, of course, but it's a useful gauge.